# How to keep the home page i18n on subsequent failed log in attempts

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, internationalization, spring-security

When a user first clicks a link to my homepage, if the link contains ?langId=fr_FR the page displays in French; so far so good. If the user makes a failed attempt to log in the page will display the error message in French, which is perfect. The problem is if a second failed attempt is made to log in. In this case the page language defaults to English.

I am not sure how to keep the page in French for the above case (i.e. any subsequent requests when the initial url contained langId=fr_FR). Should I be using a CookieLocaleResolver instead of a SessionLocaleResolver?

The site uses Spring Security and I have implemented a filter which runs before the Spring Security filters. This filter will set the LocaleContextHolder using the langId request parameter. This works great for the initial log in attempt. Any other requests made and I loose the langId parameter.

Is there something I can do in the loadByUserName() method that will allow me to persist the original langId?

Here is the config for the resolver and interceptor

```
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver" >
 <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
     <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="langId" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

**EDIT**

Using a CookieLocaleResolver instead of a SessionLocaleResolver does fix this issue. But, if users disable cookies then I am back to square one. I'd like to find a way to keep the page in French upon multiple log in attempts for a user. Any help is really appreciated Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly the sessionlocaleresolver.  Since the login attemps fail a new session is created every time ( i believe ) .

Thats why the cookielocaleresolver is working. The cookie is set and remains for your domain.

I do use the sessionlocaleresolver and havent thought about this issue yet.

One way i see should be to include the locale parameter in your form action. It is probably the easiest solution?

Comment: Interesting. Currently, we just use an <mvc:view-controller path="/logon.html" view-name="logon" /> tag. Which, will just forward the user to the logon.html page. So, using your solution I would have to make sure the page request goes through a controller. Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: Sorry, I responded to quickly and didn't understand what you were saying. I'll look at adding the langId to the action for the log in form. Thanks!